# A few questions about webRTC on android

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, native, webrtc

I have a few questions about webRTC on android. I can say I'm new about android and webRTC but I can also say I made tooo much research about webRTC on android. But still have a few questions. (some of them because of I'm new, and some of them because of I'm okey but not fully)

1. I'm trying to make an android app which is going to communicate between web browser (first choice is chrome) and android device directly (p2p we can say). So I made too much research and I found webRTC is good for me. Do you advise me something other or is it okey you think? (also I am going to code a plugin for chrome).
2. Nearly every document says 'android is not directly support webRTC'. So I need something to provide me webRTC on android. What it is? Is it native android that I have to code? Is it native (NDK) library that I have to include my project? Or is it a java lib? Or should I go for cordova/crosswalk or sth like that? I researched all but didn't find something can help me. Yeah there are documents about it but not enough..
3. Some of documents says, I need chromium. But why and how? They show me lots of linux terminal commands and even there is no a line java or C or C++ code. Even some terminal commands and links that they give is not working.
4. I read/found/tried these things as a result of my research:

Apache cordova

Crosswalk

http://www.webrtc.org/

https://github.com/webrtc

http://webrtc.github.io/samples/

http://simonguest.com/2013/08/06/bui...t-for-android/

http://orcaman.blogspot.com.tr/2014/...tc-source.html

https://github.com/pchab/ProjectRTC

https://github.com/pchab/AndroidRTC

and something more..

in a nutshell I need help. Please give me your hand. Thank you. (because I'm really very helpless and tried to do my best)
Thank you.

Comment: Here are some more links with some related to Android: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1idl_NYQhllFEFqkGQOLv8KBK8M3EVzyvxnKkHl4SuM8/edit

Comment: so thank you. i am checking it now. and i am waiting for more help you or anyone. more help will not bad . thank you again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have suggested, I recommend checking out [g.co/webrtc](http://g.co/webrtc). As I understand it, your goal is to make Android connect to a web browser using WebRTC. There are two (three) ways you can achieve that.

1. You can just use Chrome, Opera or Firefox for Android. All these browsers support WebRTC, and it allows you to use the same code for your web app, as for your Android app. With the new Add to homescreen support, as well as support for push notifications from web apps on Android, this could be a very good solution for you.
2. You can use the Android native WebRTC library, available from [WebRTC.org](http://www.webrtc.org/native-code/android). As mentioned in [my article](https://tech.appear.in/2015/05/25/Introduction-to-WebRTC-on-Android/), I recommend using the pristine.io compiled library, available from MavenCentral.
3. If you can limit your application to Lollipop, you can use WebView, which support WebRTC now iirc. I don't know much about it though.

And the best resource for getting help is [discuss-webrtc](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/discuss-webrtc). It's a lot more active than StackOverflow.

Comment: so thanks dear. Is there any document detailed more then your article about pristine,io? for exm: how can I send a text document (maybe a pdf or word doc. ) with webRTC using pristine.io compiled library. I have lots of question like this so is there a doc about pristine.io lib?
thank you again

Comment: The library is just the WebRTC.org library compiled and put on maven-central really. And no, there's not really any documentation for it except my guide at the moment, but I hope there will be more fleshed out soon. AppRTC-code is the best source, so I would play around with that (linked in my blog post)